# A function "join" and "split" must show word [5:6] and [10]

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following join in my code

```
(' '.join(s.split()[10:14])
```

But i also want to print word [16], i have tried "and", "+" etc. but no luck
Hope somebody can help me :-)

Comment: Please add an example. What's value of `s` and what do you want to print out?

Comment: What do you meany by `word [16]`? How did `+` not work, did you use `s.split()[10:14]+[16]` or `s.split()[10:14] + [s.split()[16]]`?

Comment: I guess OP wants 5th, 6th and 10th word of a string. The easiest way to do it is via an intermediate variable; you can't do it with `and` or `+`.

Comment: Indeed, want to print the 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14th word of the string, and the 16th word.
Tried both s.split()[10:14]+[16] and s.split()[10:14] + [s.split()[16]]

Comment: @Metroll Actually, that last bit `s.split()[10:14] + [s.split()[16]]` should have worked. Did you get an error?

Comment: BTW, `[10:14]` does _not_ give you "the 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14th word", but just the 10th, 11th, 12th and 13th word.

Comment: @tobias_k Well, to put it more accurately, `[10:14]` gives you the 11th, 12th, 13th and 14th word, rather than the 10th, 11th, 12th and 13th word.

Comment: @blhsing Well, if _you_ consider the element at index 0 to the the first and not the zeroth, then yes, but who does? :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do it by joining both strings after extracting them individually.**

Sample string:

```
s = '1  2  3 4 5 6  7  8  9  10 11 12  13 14 15 16 17 18 19'

' '.join(s.split()[10:14]) + ' ' + s.split()[15]
```

Also, as pointed out by @blhsing , the second join might not be needed here and only the 16th element of split can be added as a string. Also added a whitespace between the two strings.

Output:

```
Out[19]: '11 12 13 14 16
```

Comment: Perfect! :-) just like i want it

Comment: `''.join(s.split()[16])` actually joins the 17th word character by character, which is not actually what you want especially if you intend to join the strings by a space.

Comment: @blhsing, thanks for pointing that out.. have updated my answer to reflect, also added the `space` for join. However, I guess @Metroll only needed a hint & he understood how to modify it to get what he needs.

Comment: @ParvBanks This still gives the wrong result, as `' '.join(s.split()[15])` would be treating the string `s.split()[15]` as a sequence of characters, so you would end up with each character of the 16th word separated by a space. Also, with this approach there will be no space in between the 14th word and the 16th word.

Comment: @blhsing, I don't think so .. if `s` is a string of words separated by a whitespace, `s.split()` will split it into individual words and not `characters` and `s.split()[15]` will return the 16th word and not the 16th character in `s`

Comment: @ParvBanks Please run the demo to see the problem: https://repl.it/repls/BleakMotherlyAddin

Comment: @ParvBanks The `join` method in your revised code, `''.join(s.split()[15])`, is entirely redundant, since you're basically splitting the string into individual characters and then joining them back into the same string. `s.split()[15]` would've been enough.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.. have made the correction.. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that:

```
>>> s = 'But i also want to print word [16], i have tried "and", "+" etc. but no luck Hope somebody can help me :-)'
>>> a = s.split()
>>> print(' '.join([*a[10:14],a[16]]))
tried "and", "+" etc. luck
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `slice` objects with the `operator.itemgetter` method, and use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to join the slices, so that you would not have to split the same string twice or store the result of the split in a temporary variable:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain
print(' '.join(chain.from_iterable(itemgetter(slice(10, 15), slice(16, 17))(s.split()))))
```

Comment: Or this: `(lambda x: x[10:14] + [x[16]])(s.split())` :D